# Preserve command history in chronological order (in fish)

Tags: command-line, shell, fish

I have noticed that default behaviour for storing command history is only storing the latest entry.
Typing `ls` and then `ls -al` and then entering `history` would show:

```
ls -al
ls
```

Typing `ls` once more would then show:

```
ls
ls -al
```

All other occurances of these commands in the command history are now gone. This makes it hard to relearn a process I may have done a few days ago.
Is there a way to make fish preserve every command entry in the same order as they are entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no configuration to do this automatically with the history function itself, no.  From the [Fish docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/interactive.html#searchable-command-history):

> Any duplicate history items are automatically removed.

However, if the goal is simply to *capture* the what you entered so that you can review the commands later (in the proper context), that's it's entirely possible via scripting.  At a simple level, what you want to do is simply save every command entered at the prompt into a file that *doesn't* remove duplicates.

Create the following function in `~/.config/fish/conf.d/save_full_history.fish`:

```
function log_command --on-event fish_preexec
    echo $argv[1] >>  ~/.local/share/fish/fish_full_history
end
```

That does a few things:

- By having it in `~/.config/fish/conf.d`, it will automatically load the function every time Fish starts.    This is done through `conf.d` since `--on-event` (and other) hooks aren't activated in lazy-loaded Fish functions.
- Using the `--on-event fish_preexec`, the function runs just after <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed for each command.
- The function receives the full commandline that was entered as `$argv[1]`, saving it to the `~/.local/share/fish/fish_full_history` file for future review.

You could, of course, add something like a timestamp to this.  E.g.:

```
echo $(date --iso-8601=ns) --- $argv[1] >>  ~/.local/share/fish/fish_full_history
```

You could also create a separate function (it can be in the same file) that executed on `fish_posterror` to make a note in the file when the command resulted in an error.

Comment: That's a pretty cool solution. How would I go about implementing the time stamp? And what editor does Fish use when it shows my history?

Comment: @attendeapril Added a (simple) sample timestamp line to the answer, but you'll probably want to tweak it.  As for the "editor", if you mean what program is used when you just type `history` in Fish, that's going to be whatever pager is default on your system (typically `less`).  You can override that with the `PAGER` variable.  For instance, if you wanted to use [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) instead, you could `set -Ux PAGER /usr/local/bin/bat` (or whatever pager you want to use).

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer! I have been working on this here and there for a couple of days with somewhat success. 



This function seems to work:

`function log_command --on-event fish_preexec
    echo (date --iso-8601=minutes) $argv[1] >>  ~/.local/share/fish/fish_full_history
end` - But tweaking the date to a cleaner format does not seem to work: `function log_command --on-event fish_preexec
    echo (date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ') $argv[1] >>  ~/.local/share/fish/fish_full_history
end`

Comment: @attendeapril That's odd.  I copied your updated (and yes, "cleaner", I agree) `echo` statement over to my copy, and it seems to be working just fine.  When you say *"does not seem to work"*, can you elaborate?  Thanks!

Comment: I put it down for a few days and now it works. I suspect it may have been because I didn't restart my terminal application in my testing. Thanky you so much for your great help!

Comment: @attendeapril Great to hear!  You're welcome!